# How to "pull down the screen to reveal the search bar" in iPhone Messages

Tags: iphone, messages

I am trying to do a search through my messages according to  [How to Search Messages on iPhone & iPad (2022 Update)](https://www.iphonelife.com/blog/32671/tip-day-how-search-message-conversations#How%20to%20Search%20Texts%20on%20iPhone%20and%20iPad)

It says to "pull down on the screen":

[image]

However when I do that on my iPhone6s it simply scrolls. How can I pull the screen down according to that article?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep scrolling. You need to be right at the top…

[image]

<sup>Oops. I only just noticed I took a picture of Mail. Messages works exactly the same way.</sup>

Comment: I was already at the top.  In any case I have tried and tried and tried, it does not work that way on my phone.

Comment: I upvoted anyways since this should be useful to others

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to tap the top of the screen once (tap the time or date or area either side of the notch if you have one). That guide assumes you are close to the top of the list…

That gesture will [scroll you to the top](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/1619421-scrollstotop) and also show the search field. Or you have to do the drag motion several times. I like to have my finger in motion before it hits the glass when I am intending to swipe or if I have to swipe a few times, less likely to be seen as a “tap”

Also, pay attention to the edges. It matters where you start the swipe. Too close to an edge or a corner, and you get overlays and multitasking and other items.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208204
- https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/learn-basic-gestures-iph75e97af9b/ios

Next check that you didn’t turn off messages in the search settings.

[image: siri and search settings for messages on iOS 15]

If after these steps, your phone doesn’t scroll to the top, it might be time to restart it and make sure your backup plan is solid.

Comment: Thx for the input.  This does not work for me.

Comment: Ok - I added what next for when the phone isn’t behaving as expected. @WestCoastProjects

Comment: I looked through all those settings and they're already set as you show - alas no dice.  Thx for the input.  Let's see if the newer iphone coming soon works.

Comment: What iOS runs on the 6s for you?

Comment: actually the latest iOS is working /running on the phone `15.4.1` : that was a condition for my purchasing it.  There may be a physical problem with the phone since i bring it on my  construction work and give it a bit of a beating.

Comment: Nice. Sometimes people don’t put the latest that can run for often good reasons